# IIS restart during Application Pool Recycles

Tags: iis, grafana

We have two applications - WebAPI and WCF service. Our WebAPI is consuming WCF service.

We have two different app pools for both applications with different recycle settings:

1. wcf application recycles every day at 1 am fixed with overlapping sessions.
2. webapi has default recycle settings.

We are getting wierd IIS restart daily at 1 am.

No event is logged in Event Viewer.

Note: We have grafana setup to monitor server and it sends alert daily at 1 am for server down.

What could be reasons for IIS restart?

Comment: "We have grafana setup to monitor server and it sends alert daily at 1 am for server down". It is suspicious. How did grafana detect server down? Why cannot it be a false alarm?

Comment: Grafana sends alerts that server seems to be down. And if we try rdc to server we are not able to connect while the server gets up.

Comment: RDP has nothing to do with IIS, and even if you cannot connect via RDP, you cannot say "the server was down". There are ways to further troubleshoot whether the server did reboot at 1am, but find a more senior guy in your team/company to troubleshoot, or open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com . Server reboot has little to do with your web app usually, and is not programming related.

Answer (score 4):

have you seen application pool recycle in event log? as you know when recycling happened , all session in iis will destroy and a log wrote in Windows event log. so I need to send deliberate information about what you detect in your monitoring application. this is because of it might a false positive of your monitoring application. as you mentioned it didn't logged in event log, I suspected this problem Is for that. please send practical information to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It might be your application cannot `refresh` the app pools when you set their app pool refresh to happen at 1am.

I would look at the permissions given to the application pool. It could be the permissions aren't enough to restart it.

Other than that I would also recommend [enabling Logging](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/313437/how-to-enable-logging-in-internet-information-services-iis). You will find out your problem with Logging enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Look through the application pool settings under advanced setting and ensure Recycling > Generate Event Log Entry is set to true for all the entries.  This will ensure everything related to the application pool will be logged and you will be able to see the reasons for the recycle.